# Is there a nontrivial profinite word which is trivial in any group with at most d generators?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, profinite-groups, free-groups

Let $F$ be a free profinite group of rank $\aleph_0$, and let $d \in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $N_d \lhd_c F$ be the intersection of all open normal subgroups $L \lhd_o F$ for which $F/L$ can be generated by at most $d$ elements.

**Can it be that $N_d = \{1\}$?**

The equivalent question in finite groups asks whether every finite group is an image of a finite subdirect product of groups generated by at most $d$ elements:

Can it be that for every finite group $G$ there exists some $r \in \mathbb{N}$ and a finite group $H$ with normal subgroups $H_1, \dots, H_r \lhd H$ such that:

1. $ \bigcap_{i=1}^{r} H_i = \{1\}$
2. For each $1 \leq i \leq r$, $H/H_i$ can be generated by at most $d$ elements.
3. $G$ Is a homomorphic image of $H$.

Comment: The answer to the analogous question in the discrete setting is 'yes'.  For every finite subset $X\subseteq F_\infty$, there is a 2-generator finite group $Q$ and an epimorphism $q:F_\infty\to Q$ so that $q$ is injective on $X$.  The profinite version may follow, but it's not completely clear to me right now.

Comment: @HJRW Yes, for discrete groups this is true because simple groups are 2-generated but do not satisfy any law. For profinite groups the answer seems to be negative however (maybe I will write an answer when I will have the details). The reason for this lies in the following compactness argument which works for profinite groups but fails for abstract groups : If the intersection is trivial, then for any open subgroup $U \lhd_o F$ there is a FINITE intersection which is contained in $U$ (this also explains the equivalence with the formulation in finite groups).

Comment: You don't need to appeal to the classification for the discrete case.  It follows  because $F_{n+1}$ is (fully) residually $F_n$, for any $n>1$.

Comment: Yes, I believe I was mistaken in my thinking. Comment deleted.

Comment: The question in the title is different an easier than the one in the body. @HWJR seems to be answering the one in the title.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg this is a good point!!! I missed this difference, and I am actually interested in both questions. Do you consider the one in the title easier? So you expect a negative answer for it?

Comment: The one in the title would seem to indicate you just need to separate a word from 1 in a not necessarily onto homomorphism to a 2-generated finite group, which you can do since symmetric groups are 2-generated.